# Ubuntu-16-04 : How to remove wifi adaptor from wifi tray

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have disabled the board wifi because it is not working properly. so i am using usb wifi adaptor. but it's still showing in the wifi tray and that don't look good is there any way to hide this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you unload and then blacklist its driver. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: when i am trying then getting this error `modprobe: FATAL: Module wlo1 not found.`

Comment: I didn't suggest a modprobe of wlo1 at all. Please retrace your steps.

Comment: oh sorry can you help me with this "https://i.imgur.com/INDS96w.jpg" adaptor

Comment: What?? Your original question says you have an Intel 3945 but the Imgur you posted says you have a Ralink RT3290. What's going on???

Comment: sorry sir i have update the question i thought there might be a variable where i have to just pass wlo1 but it is something else so i can figured it out.

Comment: I will edit my answer to show the solution in a few minutes.

Comment: one more question sir where did you find the id of that adaptor like `rt2800pci`

Comment: There are two ways to know. The hard way is to work with wireless devices and drivers every day for 15 years. The easy way is a terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: Unbelievable sir